# How to display sub field (image) with shortcode in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, custom-fields

These are the custom fields composition:

1 Group Footer

1.1 Group Col2

1.1.1 bbcimg (this is the image ID)

1.1.2 bbc-rss (this is the RSS feed ID)

I have the following code displaying the bbc-rss:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
               <?php
                $footer = get_field('footer'); // 'footer' is your parent group
                $col2 = $footer['col2']; // 'col2' is your child group
                ?>
                <div class="widget_item widget_latest sm-m-top-50">
                    <h4 id="white" class="text-white">Latest News</h4>
                    <div class="widget_latst_item m-top-30">
                        
                        <div class="item_icon"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/img/rss/bbc_rss.png" alt="" /></div>
                        <div id="gris" class="widget_latst_item_text">
                            <p><?php echo $col2['bbc-rss'];?></p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="widget_latst_item m-top-30">
                        <div class="item_icon"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/img/rss/reuters_rss.png" alt="" /></div>
                        <div id="gris" class="widget_latst_item_text">
                            <p><?php echo $col2['reuters-rss'];?></p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="widget_latst_item m-top-30">
                        <div class="item_icon"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/img/rss/cnbc.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                        <div id="gris" class="widget_latst_item_text">
                            <p><?php echo $col2['cnbc-rss'];?></p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- End off widget item -->
            </div><!-- End off col-md-3 -->
```

I have created the image field bbcimg with the following properties:

- Field label: bbcimg
- Field Name: bbcimg
- Field Type: image
- Instructions: -
- Required: No
- Return Format: Image Array
- Preview Size: Medium(300x300)
- Library: All
- Minimum: Width 40px, Height px 40 File size - MB
- Minimum: Width - px, Height px - File size - MB
- Allowed file types: -
- Conditional Logic: -
- Wrapper Attributes: -

And the image is already uploaded in the custom field. See picture:
[image]

**Question:**

How to write the logic to display the picture on the website?

Thank you very much in advance!

been trying to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to find out what is getting returned inside the custom field.
Add a good old `print_r` to your code somewhere:

```
<?php print_r($col2['bbcimg']) ?>
```

That will print out an array of values like Array( 'url' => 'http....something.jpg', 'size'=>'full', ..etc)

Then you can identify which array value gives you the full URL to the image. Say in this case it would be a field called `url`, then you can use that value as follows:

```
<div id="gris" class="widget_latst_item_text">
     <img src="<?php echo $col2['bbcimg']['url']; ?>" alt=""/>
     <p><?php echo $col2['bbc-rss'];?></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Mikepote for your answer. I wrote your code `<?php print_r($col2['bbcimg']) ?>`  for testing it. I saw all the information that was huge and the code is working now. Thank you again! :-)